# Jquery - Getting attribute from TR html tag in IE 9

Tags: jquery, html-table, attributes

I have written a jQuery code to get an attribute from a TR tag in html. The code works in IE 8, but when I run that in IE 9 I get a error "Function expected". The code is below:

```
$(".grid tr").each(function () {

  //I've inserted an attribute called idRow in each grid row. 
  if(this.attributes("idRow") != null) //I get the "Function expected error" here
  {
      ...
  }

});
```

What's the code problem? Why it works in IE 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take that approach, you'd need...

```
this.attributes.getNamedItem('idRow').nodeValue
```

or...

```
this.attributes.item('idRow').nodeValue
```

---

...although, I'd suggest simply using `getAttribute()`.

```
this.getAttribute('idRow')
```

Comment: @Leila: I'm guessing they originally had the `attributes` object as a callable function/object, but in their efforts to be more standards compliant, removed that ability.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if($(this).attr('idRow') != undefined) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd rather use

```
$(".grid tr").each(function (tr) {

  //I've inserted an attribute called idRow in each grid row. 
  if(tr.attributes("idRow") != null) //I get the "Function expected error" here
  {
      ...
  }

});
```

Comment: That's a reference to the same element. It won't fix the error.

Comment: What does *"neither your downvote"* mean? Do you not understand why you were down-voted?

Comment: I never downvoted any answer, and I'll never do. Some SO's functions are abused and really not used for what they were intended. They are mostly used by zealous policemen - but hey you have the right to downvote and can do it. Just I don't understand who benefits from this. Peace & love (I just upvoted your answer because it's the best one and solves the problem - also I appreciated the explaination on why it works on IE8. Just to be clear)

Comment: Well, they're intended to rate the quality of a question or answer, so I would encourage you to actively up or down vote as appropriate. Doing so isn't abusing, but rather is using the feature as it was intended. Abuse happens when people vote for reasons other than the quality of the post. The one who benefits is the asker, because it's supposed to show community support for or against a post.

Comment: The limit between use and abuse cannot be detected by a compiler, neither estabilished in a RFC. I just wrote why I were disappointed and explained my point of view. I didn't mean to change your mind